# How can I bundle multiple .py files into single .exe file?

Tags: python, pyinstaller

[PROBLEM]

```
input: multiple .py files
output: a single .exe file
```

[CODE]
Test example:
I have a main.py + component.py.
[ main.py code ]

```
 #   Import packages

import Tkinter
    from Tkinter import *
    import tkFileDialog
    import tkMessageBox

#Create dummy function

def showMessage():
import subprocess
execfile("component.py")
#Add button

root = Tkinter.Tk(className="test")
button= Button(root, text="Click", command=showMessage)
button.grid(row=10, column=3, sticky = W + E)
#Pack it

root.mainloop()
```

[ component.py. code ]

```
#Import packages

import Tkinter
from Tkinter import *
import tkFileDialog
import tkMessageBox
#Create dummy function

def showMessage():
tkMessageBox.showinfo('test', 'test.')
showMessage()
```

[CURRENT RESULT]
The exe file will check for component.py and because it will not find it, it will fail to open the msgBox.
Note: I have build only the main.py file
Note: I am using python 2.7.10 + pyinstaller 3.0.

Comment: You can consider using py2exe

Comment: yes. I understand your point, in the same time the app is written in python 2.7.10 and py2exe supports at least python 3. Nonetheless I will keep digging ...

Comment: Please have a look at Note which I am added.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using py2exe module.

py2exe turns Python programs into packages that can be run on other Windows computers without needing to install Python on those computers.

Here it is link for the same.

http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/Tutorial

**Note:**

Python 2.6, 2.7, 3.0, 3.1

For Python 2.6, the DLL you need is called MSVCR90.dll. Py2exe is not able to automatically include this DLL in your dist directory, so you must provide it yourself.

To complicate things, there is more than one version of this DLL in existance, each with the same filename. You need the same version that the Python interpreter was compiled with, which is version 9.0.21022.8. Through the remainder of these instructions, hover your mouse over the dll file (or the vcredist_x86.exe installer executable) to confirm which version you've got. You'll need the vcredist_x86.exe that contains the Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 Redistributable Package published 29-11-2007, so not the VS2008 SP1 one (tested with Python 2.7.1).

As for older versions of Python, you need to check redist.txt within your Visual Studio installation to see whether you have the legal right to redistribute this DLL. If you do have these rights, then you have the option to bundle the C runtime DLL with you application. If you don't have the rights, then you must have your users run the redistributable C runtime installer on their machines.

Comment: thanks. In the mean time I've found a workaround, namely consider component.py as a separate module. In the other words: "from component import showMessage". I will play with this a bit and if I stumble on other situations there is a chance I will move to other installer.

Answer (score 1):

I came across this issue with python 3. I just used cx_freeze. It makes executables fairly well, and It works with setuptools. It does leave you with a lot of extra files. To get around this I just developed a simple installer that bundles everything together and installs all of the files into "Program Files".

I used Inno Setup. It is really easy to use. I recommend this approach. Instead of spending hours to develop a single exe, bundle all of your files into a single exe installer which installs all of the files into the correct location. http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php Inno Setup even has a setup wizard that does everything for you.